# AC analysis of three-stage BJT amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, feedback, gain

I have designed a three-stage BJT amplifier in LTspice, CE-CE-CC. I have calculated the gain on every stage using the small-signal model.

[image]

The problem is that the overall gain I get by multiplying the gain on every stage is 37% higher than the gain I get from LTspice.

[Here's the link](https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:o:/g/personal/tp064501_mail_apu_edu_my/Ej-5BjAWQ39HmoA0fxpEicoBhcFWfsswuQs7AKIDXSRo0Q) to my circuit and calculation on SharePoint.

Comment: Hmm. Your 1st stage DC biasing, R1 and R2, is insane. Do you see why? The loading at the emitter is the only thing that matters in your 1st stage case. I'd like to see your design process.

Comment: We just started this module. We are learning to use LTSpice and do the calculations. So I dont have a design process. I literally picked a circuit, put some values randomly until I meet the requirements.

Comment: Those two circuits are different circuits.

Comment: Link with your calculations is broken, which makes the question homework with no attempt at a solution.  Please edit your question with that data added to the question, not a breakable link.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked through your calculations but have you taken into account the attenuation between the stages due to the loading on each stage of the input resistance of the following stage.

For instance, there is an attenuating potential divider formed by the output resistance of the first stage (5k) acting with the input resistance of the second stage and then another attenuating potential divider formed by the output resistance of the second stage (550R) acting with the input resistance of the third stage.

So you would need to calculate those two attenuations and multiply them by the gains of the 3 stages to calculate the overall gain.

For the first two stages (common emitter amps) the gain of each stage without a load would be simply :-

Av = -Rc/(Re + re) where re = 25mV/Ic, Rc is the collector resistance and Re is the unbypassed emitter resistance.

The gain of the last stage (common collector) will be a fraction less than one (unity).

So the basic gain of a CE amp with no load is:-

[image: Gain Equation]

If we were to consider the CE gain with a load added we must multiply the above gain equation by the potential divider equation and the gain with the added load becomes:

[image: Gain equation]

Now, you may have seen the equation for the CE gain with load added more commonly expressed as:-

[image: Gain equation]

This can be rewritten as:-

[image: Gain equation]

By comparing equation 1 and equation 2 you should be able to see that they are basically the same equation.

Comment: Has the schematic in the question changed?

Comment: @OskarSkog The circuit posted in the question has some different component values to the one accessed in the link, although now when I click on the link it says "access denied". Also the circuit posted in the question, which was added later, has a source resistance which will affect the overall gain. The circuit posted in the link has no source resistance.